# How can I update an existing <style> from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to alter a `<style>` from the client-side - something like this:

```
<head>
    <style>
        img.Bordered
        {   border-style: dashed;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnBorderChanged () {
            //Set "border-style" to "solid" for Bordered images.
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

What is the process for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript and http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html

These articles explain how to dynamically add and remove entire styles.

Note that the first article give you a pretty good cross-browser set of functions to use. The quirksmode article basically explains how it all works.

Comment: The hunlock link was perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

using jquery's css method:

http://api.jquery.com/css/

e.g:

```
$("img.Bordered").css('border-style', 'solid');
```